# Replace latitude to longitude

Tags: leaflet, postgis, latitude-longitude, postgresql-9.4

I am getting polygon geom as text which showing the first longitude, latitude ... I am creating GeoJSON and drawing on leaflet... but leaflet standard first latitude then longitude. I am using PostGIS how I can to change in polygon...  if I have point geometry it is very easy I can change `st_x`,`st_y` for point.... but there I want to change to the overall boundary of the polygon, my created goem is

```
[[72.96699,31.96872],[72.9679,31.9669]]
```

while I want to convert as

```
[[31.96872,72.96699],[31.9669,72.9679]]
```

overall my query is

```
(SELECT row_to_json(fc)
     FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features
     FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type
      , st_asgeojson(lg.geom , 5 ,0)::json As geometry
      , row_to_json((SELECT l FROM (SELECT id, distt_name) As l
        )) As properties
     FROM (SELECT gid as id, distt_name , geom FROM tbl_districts 
      where distt_name like '%') As lg) As f )  
    As fc)
```

Answer (score 1):

- [GeoJSON is accepted by Leaflet.](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#geojson)
- [GeoJSON specifies x,y not y,x. So it's already longitude,latitute](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#appendix-A.1). Look here.

  ```
    SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON( ST_MakePoint(1,2) );
                 st_asgeojson             
    --------------------------------------
     {"type":"Point","coordinates":[1,2]}
    (1 row)
  ```

You should generate GeoJSON using `jsonb_build_object` and `ST_AsGeoJSON`.